# Working with CSS to improve website appearance

Tags: css, user-interface

I am looking to develop websites, that have a updated and modern look and feel. A sample site is [Manta Media Inc](http://www.manta.com/)

I am guessing those are stylesheets to some extent.
What should I search for on google, if I want to learn how to create a web interface similar to that?  My expertiese is in .Net applicatio development, not quite the User Interface side.
Any reference to websites is also appreciated.

Comment: That is HTML and CSS. You have to learn HTML and CSS.

Comment: You can't search for creativity, talent and individual flare, although you can look around the web for inspiration to get you started!

Comment: For an `updated and modern look and feel` you also need to know graphic design.

Comment: @Šime Vidas, I know basic HTML & CSS. How would I start to learn "advanced" level ?

Comment: @user I recommend the specs: [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) and [HTML 4.01 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/). As for the CSS spec, what you want to achieve is get a good overview of all the CSS properties. I have compiled a nice overview [here](http://vidasp.net/CSS-properties.html). As for HTML, you want to learn which elements there are in HTML. Again, my overview is [here](http://vidasp.net/HTML-structure-diagram.html).

Comment: @user - Practice.  Read about user interface design.  Read about graphic design and color.  Just get some ideas on why you like certain sites and look at the details of the site and start playing.

Comment: Are you looking to design websites, or to use CSS to implement designs done by someone else? Because those are two different skills.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning advanced CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104478/learning-advanced-css)

Comment: @Paul... end goal is to design my own websites that have current look and feel (not implement CSS on someone else's work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by looking at a site like [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com), the earlier video tutorials are a decent look into beginning to "template" a site. You will also have to look into learning about Photoshop or Illustrator (adobe) in order to get those background images created.

The site you linked to is a simple site with four boxes. Learn to use 1. floats and clears, 2. position and display, 3. padding and margins.

Comment: @superUntitled... thank you. That site seems to be very well qrganized.

Answer (score 1):

If you‘re looking to design websites to have an updated and modern look and feel, then you have to learn about design. I’ve no idea where to start with that.

If you’re looking to implement existing designs using CSS, there’s a couple of books that are well worth reading:

- [‘CSS: The Definitive Guide’, by Eric Meyer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527330)
- [‘Bulletproof Web Design’, by Dan Cederholm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321509021)